# How much transfer time do I need in Mumbai airport?

Tags: air-travel, india, airports, mumbai

I will take a two domestic flights, from Varanasi to Mumbai then from Mumbai to Kochi. How much transfer time do I need? Will the flights be commonly delayed?

Comment: On one booking or separate bookings? Check-in luggage? Which airlines do you intend to fly?

Comment: One booking with normal check in luggage. I'm comparing Air India and Indigo. with Air India its a 1h30 layover and with indigo it would be a 2h30 layover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [expertflyer](http://www.expertflyer.com/air/travelInformation.do), the minimum connecting time (MCT) for domestic to domestic flights is nominally 30 minutes. Air India flights have a range of MCT from 0:45 up to 2:00 depending on arrival and departure terminal and flight number. Indigo has an MCT of 1 hour.

To see the typical delay, you could look up the flight numbers on [flightstats](http://www.flightstats.com/). Taking a sample VNS-BOM flight AI696, it shows a poor on-time rating of 0.6 out of 5 with an average delay of 32 minutes. Today's flight arrived 65 minutes late. This flight could connect to AI681 BOM-COK with a 90 minute layover. Today, AI681 departed 49 minutes late and arrived 41 minutes late. It has an on-time rating of 2 out of 5 with an average delay of 22 minutes.

Similarly for Indigo 6E 223, BOM-COK, flightstats shows an on-time rating of 4.9 and average delay of 9 minutes. 6E 711 VNS-BOM shows on-time performance of 3.6 our of 5 with an average delay of 28 minutes.

If you search for flights from BOM-COK on [Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) or you'll see there are typically only two Air India flights per day, and only one flight per day from VNS-BOM.

It would be advisable to use the above sites to research your flights and delay performance if you have a tight connection.

If you bought a single ticket and missed your connection, the airline would rebook you on the next flight available, but this is very likely to be the next day.

Comment: Looks like the Air India connection is a bit risky, if I understand this answer right.

Comment: @Willeke It does seem to be a tighter connection and on an airline with a poor on-time performance at that airport